# Installing multiple multiple versions with rpm

Tags: rpm

How to specify destination path for new package in linux rpm?

Example:
*rpm --install kibana-6.0.1-x86_64.rpm*
will install: *rpm -qa: kibana-6.0.1-1.x86_64*
It will sit in /usr/share/kibana

The next installation *rpm --install kibana-6.0.2-x86_64.rpm*    will sit in the same /usr/share/kibana.

I prefer them living together as **/usr/share/kibana-xxx**

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** As OP suggested, [SoftwareCollection](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/docs/) does look promising. It doesn't support `kibana` and explaining it how to do it is beyond this answer.

`rpm` untars and install the package as the package was designed in its spec file. Depending on what you are doing, you can look the command `rpm2cpio` which untars the `.rpm` file on to a working directory. You can then move the file to any directory you want.

```
# Download the rpm to a local directory, /tmp/kibana-6.0.2    
$ cd /tmp/kibana-6.0.2

# Following will untar kibana-6.0.2 assuming / directory is /tmp/kibana-6.0.2
$ rpm2cpio kibana-6.0.2-x86_64.rpm | cpio -idum  # man cpio for option details
```

Repeat the procedure for `kibana-6.0.1`. Note, `rpm2cpio` command will not alter the `rpmdb`, therefore this operation will not be visible to `rpm -qa | grep kibana` command.

Comment: Is it the same as putting the equivalent *tar.gz ? Or there is some advantage in the practice? What is good practice of managing XX_HOME env variable in that case?

Comment: If you mean by source tarball, yes there is a difference. A source tarball will not have any of the already built files (during packaging) whereas `rpm2cpio` will have it.

Answer (score 3):

The more systematic approach is to use [Software Collections](http://softwarecollections.org/). On that site already exists some collections (e.g. python33), and there is documentation how to create your own collection.